# Can't connect GA4 properties with Custom Channel Group using Power BI connector

Tags: google-analytics-api, powerbi-desktop

I have discovered an issue in GA connector (2.0 implementation) for Power BI. I can't connect GA4 properties with Custom Channel Group using Power BI connector, I get the exception above:

```
Expression.Error: The field 'description' of the record wasn't found.
Details:
    apiName=customChannelGroup:6299986805
    uiName=Custom Channel Group
    category=Attribution
```

I opened a ticket in Power BI support to discard issues with the tool. Conclusion: Microsoft Team told me to report this issue to Google Team, because they just host the API and don't develop it. I tried to open an issue in GA [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues) but I don't have permission to open it in the right component. I hope this posts reaches someone that could help me with that.

Here's how to reproduce the error.

GA4 has this feature to create Customized Channel Grouping in the GA UI.
Step to reproduce:
Admin > Data display > Channel groups > Create new channel group

[GA4 UI to create customized channel grouping.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iInEw.png)

Here just create a customized channel grouping.

In Power BI Desktop, let's obtain data to reproduce the error.

Step to reproduce:

Obtain data > More... > Search Google Analytics > Select Google Analytics > Connect > Login to an account that has permission to visualize the property > Select 2.0 (Beta) > Click on the property with Custom Channel Group created

You will obtain this error:

[Obtain data error in Power BI Desktop.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBoVq.png)

If you already connected the property before creating a Custom Channel Group and try to refresh it in Transform data or Refresh data after creating it, you will obtain these errors:

[Refresh data error in Power BI Desktop.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7FI9.png)

[Transform data error in Power BI Desktop.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4oRj.png)

I did a workaround that fixes: Delete the Custom Channel Group in the property. Do someone know how to connect a property in Power BI with Custom Channel Group created?

Comment: Who created the connector? Why not contact them